# Laravel form data not posting to update controller

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I am debugging a piece of code one of my team members has submitted, I am not too familiar with Laravel so bear with me if I've missed anything, but basically the form will submit and be redirected to the correct update controller, but when I try to get the result of one of the changed fields in the form, it is just blank.

Index Form Data

```
<form method="POST" action= "{{ route('apparatus_codes.update' , $apparatusCode->id )}}"  class="is-readonly" > 
            @csrf
            @method('PUT')
      <tr id="table{{ $apparatusCode->id}}" data-target=".table{{ $apparatusCode->id}}"> 
      <td class="main-bg"> {{ $apparatusCode->id}} </td>
      <td class="data main-bg"><input name ="rent" id="rent" value = "{{ $apparatusCode->rent}}"/></td>
     <input type="submit" id="save-button" class="save"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="/../../img/save-icon.svg" alt="save icon">
</form>
```

Controller

```
public function update(ApparatusCodesRequest $request, $id)
{
     // find selected apparatus code details
     $apparatusCodes = ApparatusCodes::find($id);
     $test = $request->input('rent');
     echo "TEST".$test;
}
```

If I echo the $apparatusCodes variable, this will display the correct data from the form on page load. However, I have an input field on the rent field, and the changed value for this field will not come through onto the controller. Also if I echo $request->all or dd($request->all()) there will be no data coming through. I can't tell why nothing is coming through when my form looks to be similar to others I have seen?

There are no errors appearing, it is reaching the intended controller ok it seems, but just not able to retrieve any of the inputted data. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Routes file

```
Route::post('/apparatus_codes/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApparatusCodesController::class, 'update'] )->name('apparatus_codes.update');
```

ApparatusCodesRequest.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

use App\Models\ApparatusCodes;

class ApparatusCodesRequest extends FormRequest
{   
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // initalising so that memo rule doesn't throw error when creating new apparatus code
        $stored_memo = '';

        // this is returning id of current apparatusCode
        $apparatusCodes_id = $this->route('apparatusCodes');

        // this request is used for both create, and update 
        // we don't want to check for a stored memo when validating a create request 
        if(!$apparatusCodes_id == null){
                
            // getting the current memo for grantor
            // used to check that memo has been updated
            $stored_memo = ApparatusCodes::where('id', $apparatusCodes_id)->pluck('memo')->firstOrFail();
        }
        

        return [           
        ];
    }

    public function messages() 
    {
        return [
            'memo.not_in' => 'An update to the memo field is required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please try changing method name from post to put in web.php file for your route ?

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar - I did that, and get the following error message "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, PUT, PATCH, DELETE." Note I also tested changing the form method to PUT as well, but it then doesn't reach the update controller

Comment: Can you add what you get in request data in question ?

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar - Thanks for the responses, if I echo $request, I get some information such as the following - "POST /apparatus_codes/1 HTTP/1.1 Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8 Cache-Control: max-age=0 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Cookie:" The apparatus_codes/1 refers to the ID of the current row.

Comment: Sorry, but can you try one last thing, add `dd(request()->all())` or `dd($request->all());` at first line of your update method in controller and see what data you see

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar - Sorry I should of put that in the question, if I do that I just get an empty array

Comment: Interesting. Mind editing your post with the contents of your `ApparatusCodesRequest` class, please?

Comment: @GaryThomas - Added - This possibly could be where I'm going wrong, I'm really not too sure what should be in here, I know at some point I'll probably have to do the DB validation inside the return, but I'm not sure if this then has anything to do with the form value coming across?

Comment: @macca4244 thanks! Unfortunately I'm no further to solving the issue. I have essentially all your code in a test project and it is working perfectly. Looking at the ids and data attributes in your HTML... Do you have some JavaScript with a click event on `id="save-button"` or something that is submitting the form perhaps and not setting the `id="rent"` value correctly?

Comment: Hi from ur form it is using the method "PUT" but in  the route the it is using the post method. You can edit the route to be ` Route::put('/apparatus_codes/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\ApparatusCodesController::class, 'update'] )->name('apparatus_codes.update'); ` instead of the Route::post

Comment: @GaryThomas - Oh my, thank you so much., there was a piece of javascript which called all buttons with the save class to show/hide another button based on if it was clicked. I commented this out and it seems to be working ok. It's strange though, I'm not too sure why this would affect the post variables as it's still submitting over to the right place. Is there anyway to interrogate the buttons within a form, like showing different states when I'm using the input type button? I know it's easy using buttons instead of input types then calling AJAX, but it kept submitting the form on itself.

Comment: @macca4244 Is there more than one `input` on the source of the page which has an `id="rent"`? If so, your JavaScript will be taking the first value from the very first `<input id="rent"...` on the page, which may not be the one from the form you are trying to submit.

Comment: @GaryThomas - Well the form I have there is within a loop which displays a list of records from the database, so I guess there will be multiple input id's as "rent", but its all within the one form, would that matter ?

Comment: Also feel free to mark your response as answer as it solved my issue, cheers!